# c struct instantiation in c2nim wrapper

Tags: nim-lang

I am trying to put together a nim wrapper for the clap AudioPlugin API.

I am using scripts to try and automate as much of the conversion as possible using c2nim to do the converting. I realize that some stuff will need to be tweaked by hand, but I am not sure what the best practice is for this case:

this is the original c code:

```
typedef struct clap_version {
  stable
  uint32_t major;
  uint32_t minor;
  uint32_t revision;
} clap_version_t;

#define CLAP_VERSION_MAJOR ((uint32_t)1)
#define CLAP_VERSION_MINOR ((uint32_t)1)
#define CLAP_VERSION_REVISION ((uint32_t)1)
#define CLAP_VERSION_INIT {CLAP_VERSION_MAJOR, CLAP_VERSION_MINOR, CLAP_VERSION_REVISION}

static const CLAP_CONSTEXPR clap_version_t CLAP_VERSION = 
{
    CLAP_VERSION_MAJOR,
    CLAP_VERSION_MINOR,
    CLAP_VERSION_REVISION
};
```

c2nim is converting this to the following nim code:

```
type
  clap_version* {.bycopy.} = object
    major*: uint32
    minor*: uint32
    revision*: uint32


const
  CLAP_VERSION_MAJOR* = (cast[uint32](1))
  CLAP_VERSION_MINOR* = (cast[uint32](1))
  CLAP_VERSION_REVISION* = (cast[uint32](1))
  CLAP_VERSION_INIT* = (CLAP_VERSION_MAJOR, CLAP_VERSION_MINOR,
   CLAP_VERSION_REVISION)

var CLAP_VERSION*: clap_version = CLAP_VERSION_INIT
```

This results in an error " Error: type mismatch: got '(uint32, uint32, uint32)' for '(1, 1, 1)' but expected 'clap_version = object'"

I understand the error. But I am not sure what the best practice solution would be.

I could correct the nim file by hand, but then I would have to do this every time I regenerate the wrapper, anyone else using the contributing to the project would also need to know to do this.

I can automate the correction, building it into the generator script with some string replace. That will work fine as long as the file in the original API does not change too much.

Is there a more "nimonic" way to solve this using c2nim?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would automate the fix. In the generator scripts I would find the line that instantiates CLAP_VERSION, and replace it with the following:

```
var CLAP_VERSION*: clap_version = clap_version(
  major: CLAP_VERSION_MAJOR,
  minor: CLAP_VERSION_MINOR,
  revision: CLAP_VERSION_REVISION,
)
```

This solves the problem for me, but I feel is might bite me in the back later. Might there be a better way?